# Issue while submit to app store - "you are already has a valid ios distribution certificate"

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes-store

enter image description hereI am trying to submit my updated version of app to app store in my machine.

While exporting I am getting the error "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate”.

Previously it was done by another person in one another machine, but i am not having the old certificate and provisioning profile.

I created the certificate and provisioning profiles, so all my code signing identities are on my machine. I'm able to run the app in device with the same certificate, I can create ipa in my machine and install the ipa in iPad its working fine, but unable to submit to app store.

I am using Xcode 6.3.2, Please anyone guide me on this.

Comment: Have you instal  Xcode 7 in your machine.

Comment: check the bundle ids

Comment: No am in xcode 6.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have created an additional distribution certificate. Login to your developer account manually and check this. If you do have two, then delete the older one (which I will assume was created by the previous developer).